# Postgresql count of occurrences in multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have got a table with several visits of patients to several doctors, and each visit has got its own `note` column, for a staff member to insert notes from the visit.

Each visit has got a column for each Note from the visit, made by a staff member. e.g. `Note_visit1`, `Note_visit2`, `Note_visit3`. 
Each visit has also got a record of the staff's ID e.g. `StaffID_visit1`, `StaffID_visit2`, `StaffID_visit3`.

My problem is trying to answer this question:

**The number of notes made by each staff member on each patient.**

The table looks something like this, ignore the dumb notes.

```
patientID|  Note_V1  |  StaffID_v1  |  Note_V2  |  StaffID_v2  |    
1        |  "cat"    |  101         |  "dog"    |  102         |  
2        |  "camel"  |  105         |  "rat"    |  101         |
```

Comment: Note that this is why you normalize tables; it makes queries such as this much easier.  The table design is bad — unconditionally bad — not least because such queries are hard.  Also, you seem to be missing crucial data, like date and time of each visit.  Oh well, ...

Comment: Im not missing those fields I just chose not to include it here as it would just take up too much space in the post. 
Do you have any suggestions to improve the table?

Comment: Table `PatientVisit`: columns `PatientID`, `StaffID`, `Note`, (Date/Time,)...  You might decide you want a `VisitID` column too, which might be an auto-allocated increasing number (sequence, ...).  Then your query is essentially trivial.  You also don't run into problems with someone who visits 70 times not having enough space for all their visits, and all sorts of other goodies.  If you have 3 visits in a single row, you have to write each condition out 3 times — and worry about whether nulls screw things up when only the visit 1 columns hold data.

Comment: So what you're saying is that i should enter each new visit in the table as a row with a unique **VisitID**, and not new columns then. That makes more sense yea. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Yes, each visit shoudl be a separate record in the PatientVisit table.  Have you covered normalization yet?  What you've got is an 'array' (of fixed size) in the columns of a table — that doesn't even count as 2NF.

Comment: Allright all do that then! Thanks @JonathanLeffler!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
select patient_id, staffid, count(*)
from ((select patient_id, staffid_v1 as staffid, note_v1 as note
       from visits
      ) union all
      (select patient_id, staffid_v2 as staffid, note_v2 as note
       from visits
      ) union all
      (select patient_id, staffid_v3 as staffid, note_v3 as note
       from visits
      )
     ) v
where note <> ''
group by patient_id, staffid;
```